# How does 'this' work in constructor function for Object creation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am really struggling to understand how does `this` works in `constructor function` for object creation in Javascript environment.

below is the code snippet:

```
function Employee() {
    basicSalary = 12000;
    overtime = 10;
    rate = 200;
    this.getWage = function () {
        return basicSalary+(overtime*rate);
    }
}
let emp = new Employee();
console.log(emp.basicSalary);//undefined
console.log(emp.getWage());//14000
```

in above code I am getting `undefined` for `basicSalary` variable. So in order to get `basicSalary` value I prefix it with `this` inside function like:

```
this.basicSalary = 12000;
```

But, in doing so I am getting error in accessing `getWage()` method. It says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: basicSalary is not defined
    at Employee.getWage (index.js:6)
    at index.js:11
```

However, if I prefix `this` to the `basicSalary` in returning statement inside `getWage()` function, I am able to access both `basicSalary` variable and `getWage()` method.

Also If I replace all my code to `factory function` i.e. Object literal type like here:

```
function employee(){
    return {
        basicSalary : 12000,
        overtime : 10,
        rate : 200,
        getWage:function(){
            return this.basicSalary+(this.overtime*this.rate); // accessing values through `this`
        }
    };
}

const e2 = employee();
console.log(e2.basicSalary);
console.log(e2.getWage());
```

Now I am easily able to get both `basicSalary` and `getWage()` method. Only thing that I needed to do was put `this` in `return` statement inside `getWage()` method.

in both these approaches `this` works differently. I am confused. Please share some knowledge on how to use `this` in Javascript.

Comment: I can help you with the article I came across when I was trying to figure out how 'this' works in JavaScript. https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: ok. I am seeing it. thanks for sharing

Comment: “In both this approaches `this` works differently ” Why do you think that? What do you perceive as different? The biggest difference between `basicSalary = ...` and `this.basicSalary = ...` is that the first creates a variable and the second creates an object property. You cannot refer to an object property as if it was a variable (your first attempt to fix it). The last example is almost the same as the previous one, except you are creating the object explicitly vs having `new` create it for you.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are either (implicitly) declaring new local variables (scoped to the *execution* of the function), or referencing global variables that exist in a higher scope.

They are not bound to the object returned with a `new`.

In the second case you are returning an object literal, so they are bound to it, obviously.

Amit’s code is good. You can also do this:

```
function Employee() {
    this.basicSalary = 12000;
    this.overtime = 10;
    this.rate = 200;
    this.getWage = () =>  this.basicSalary + (this.overtime*this.rate)
}
```

If you have arrow functions though, you also have ES6 classes. That may be a better match.

Comment: Since I can see how your answer could be misinterpreted: This example works exactly the same with a normal function. The arrow function is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the article I commented you can try this.

```js
function Employee() {
    this.basicSalary = 12000;
    this.overtime = 10;
    this.rate = 200;
    this.getWage = function () {
        return this.basicSalary + (this.overtime*this.rate);
    }
}
let emp = new Employee();
console.log(emp.basicSalary);//12000
console.log(emp.getWage());//14000
```